# El campo Default/expression en MySQL(Worbench) ¿Para que sirve?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy realizando una base de datos en MySQL con MySQL Worbench y me pregunto cómo puede ayudarme en mi base de datos.

**¿Para qué sirve en el momento de crear una tabla el campo default/expression?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El atributo **default/expression** establece el valor por defecto para la columna cuando en un insert este no es proporcionado.

Por ejemplo dada la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE persona
(nombre char(50),
apellidos char(50),
direccion char(50) default 'desconocida',
pais char(50) default 'España');
```

Sí hacemos un insert

```
INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellidos)
VALUES ( 'Pedro', 'Picapiedra');
```

Nos generará el siguiente registro:

```
nombre   | apellido   | direccion   | país
---------------------------------------------
Pedro    | Picapiedra | desconocida | España
```